# Iterate through multiple lists to apply the same changes to each

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

As an example, let's say I have 3 different lists:

```
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
lst2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
lst3 = ['h', 'i']
```

And I want to make the same changes to each one such that I can still call each list individually but with the new changes. So suppose I wanted to add a 'z' to every element in the above lists. I want to be able to call `lst3` for example and get `lst3 = ['hz', 'iz']`.

I tried group each list into a list of lists: `lists = [lst1, lst2, lst3]`

Then applied my changes using `[[(x + 'z') for x in z] for z in lsts]`. But that just returns a list of lists.

I also tried using a for loop:

```
for each in lsts:
    each = [(x + 'z') for x in each]
```

but when I call `lst3` for example, it appears that the changes weren't done in-place.

Essentially I want to have the following output, so that each list is still separated by with the applied changes. Any insight into how I can achieve this?

```
lst1 = ['az', 'bz', 'cz']
lst2 = ['dz', 'ez', 'fz', 'gz']
lst3 = ['hz', 'iz']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track here:

```
for each in lists:
    each = [(x + 'z') for x in each]
```

The trouble here is that `each` is the list you're working on initially, but afterward, `each` is the new list. You're changing the variable `each`, *not the original list.*

This is easily remedied by using a slice assignment:

```
for each in lists:
    each[:] = [(x + 'z') for x in each]
```

In other words, you're replacing the *contests* of `each` (which is still the original list) with the new list, and this gets you the result you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result from `[[(x + "z") for x in z] for z in lists]` back to `lst1`, `lst2`, `lst3`:

```py
lst1 = ["a", "b", "c"]
lst2 = ["d", "e", "f", "g"]
lst3 = ["h", "i"]

lists = [lst1, lst2, lst3]

lst1, lst2, lst3 = [[(x + "z") for x in z] for z in lists]

print(lst1)
print(lst2)
print(lst3)
```

Prints:

```
['az', 'bz', 'cz']
['dz', 'ez', 'fz', 'gz']
['hz', 'iz']
```

Comment: For the multi-assignment, it doesn't even have to be a list, could be a generator.